# ORA-00119 & ORA-00130 when trying to startup Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm having a problem with an Oracle database. Yesterday everything was working fine, I had an application that was using the database and there was no problem. At the end of the day I installed MySQL on the same server (I don't think it can be related but anyway..) and had to restart the server.
Today when I was using my application to access the Oracle database I had a connection error:

`Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: 
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

Then I went to the server. All the services are up and the database is down.

When I try to login normally, I get an error saying that Oracle is not available, and can only connect as sysdba. Then when I try to start the database up I get the following errors:

[image: SQL Plus console display]

Any help is apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my teammate found the answer to the problem.

He changed some details in the file 'tnsnames.ora' at ORACLE_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN. He just replaced “hostname” by “localhost”.

`WP5 =`
  `(DESCRIPTION =`
   `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <b>localhost</b>)(PORT = 1521))`
    `(CONNECT_DATA =`
      `(SERVER = DEDICATED)`
      `(SERVICE_NAME = WP5)`
    `)`
  `)`

`LISTENER_WP5 =<br>`
  `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <b>localhost</b>)(PORT = 1521))`

A new startup (without leaving sqlplus) made it work!

[image: Oracle success console message]

PS: We still have no ideia why/how it was working before, since the file updated date dates from about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: fact is that de db won't crash when you make changes to your tnsnames when it is already running, it could refuse to start indeed

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the ORACLE_SID?
I think the problem is there

Comment: This should be a comment. Unless you are sure it is the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: Yes, I had the ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME set.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm new here and don't know the exact rules to post!